# Разный цвет текста в textView swift 4

Tags: swift4, uitextview

День добрый,
Столкнулся с проблемой
Как можно менять цвет текста в textView ( текст берется из JSON )
Пример: в тексте есть слово “Привет” и оно будет зеленым цветом, а остальной текст будет черным ( Слово привет может встречаться несколько раз )
И как сделать чтобы текст правильно делал перенос строк?
пробовал

```
textView.typingAttributes[NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor] = UIColor.green
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Работа со строками в `Swift` то еще удовольствие. Чтобы "раскрасить" текст, который берется из JSON, Вам нужно присваивать `attributedText`.

Пример:

```
// MARK: - нужные строки
let stringFromJson = "Привет пока привет пока приВет"
let stringToColor = "Привет"
// MARK: - Приводим к строкам с которыми будем работать
let someAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: stringFromJson)
let rawString = stringFromJson as NSString
// MARK: - Подготавливаемся к поиску диапазонов слова для покраски
var ranges: [NSRange] = []
var range: NSRange
var startLocation = 0
// MARK: - ищем диапазоны
repeat {
    range = rawString.range(of: stringToColor,
                            options: .caseInsensitive,
                            range: NSRange(location: startLocation, length: rawString.length - startLocation))
    if range.location != NSNotFound {
        startLocation = range.location + range.length
        ranges.append(range)
    }
} while range.location != NSNotFound
// MARK: - задаем найденным диапазонам нужный цвет
let attributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.green]
for range in ranges {
    someAttributedString.addAttributes(attributes, range: range)
}
// MARK: - присваиваем
textView.attributedText = someAttributedString
```

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Домой приду - проверю

Comment: Заранее Спасибо!

Comment: Как быть если мне нужно три разных цвета или более
Пример: Привет - зеленый , пока - красный, машина - синий, а остальной текст - черный 
?

Comment: @samentyevtriboy по-простому - точно так же для других нужных слов ищете их `Range` и для этого `Range` задаете нужный цвет. Чуть сложнее, но универсальнее - смотрите в сторону регулярных выражений.

Comment: у меня получается что меняет цвет только в одном слове (((
А можно это провернуть через switch?
нужные слова добавить в массив - и под определенным рейсом - определенный цвет